# matplotlib how to visualize scatter & plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to connect scatter by line and show legend.. So I use plt.plot and plt.scatter..
but plot and scatter have each legend and show duplication. I think only plot has legend information because I define plt.legend before plt.scatter...

1. Can you tell me nice method to connect scatter?
2. Can you tell me why scatter has legend??

``[image]`python```

```
for index in range(len(xvalue_list)):
 plt.plot(xvalue_list, yvalue_list)
 plt.legend(graph_legend_list[index], fontsize = '10', fancybox=True)
 plt.scatter(xvalue_list, yvalue_list)    
 plt.xlabel(xlabel)
 plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you provide the necessary variables, such as graph_legend_list, xvalue_list, yvalue_list?

These would make debugging your issue much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 4 legends, where each character of the desired label is mapped to one of the elements in the plot. This is clearly not useful. Instead, create one single legend.

```
for index in range(len(xvalue_list)):
    plt.plot(xvalue_list, yvalue_list, marker="o", label=graph_legend_list[index])

plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.legend(fontsize = '10', fancybox=True)
plt.show()
```